# JupyterHub on Kubernetes: Error creating: pods "hub-b564f4485-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy: []

Tags: kubernetes, jupyterhub

On a on prem cluster(installed with Gravity: https://gravitational.com/gravity/docs/cluster/#pod-security-policies) with security policies, I’m trying to do a helm install of the Zero to Jupyterhub helm chart and I encounter the following error.

```
Error creating: pods "hub-b564f4485-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy: []
```

I'm on version 0.8.2 of Zero to JupyterHub

The relevant files, to inspect, I think are:

- The Chart: https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/tree/8c9550d4fd8de825e6c87ae79e3c513b74e19bcd/jupyterhub
- Values file: https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/tree/8c9550d4fd8de825e6c87ae79e3c513b74e19bcd/jupyterhub/values.yaml
- (Not sure.) https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/tree/8c9550d4fd8de825e6c87ae79e3c513b74e19bcd/jupyterhub/templates/hub/deployment.yaml

I have existing privileged pod security policies(all powerful, can do everything) that I can attach(to a serviceaccount for eg.) or set if required. Please let me know.
Ref: https://gravitational.com/gravity/docs/cluster/#pod-security-policies
As you can see there, there is a PSP `privileged` which allows unrestricted use to the cluster.

Comment: Please share you env configuration (Pod YAMLs. Security policy conf, etc). Is hard to guess how you set security polices. Could you also share link to this Helm chart? Cluster is On-Prem or local?

Comment: @PjoterS. Thanks for being polite! It was a late night dump so I forgot to give more context.

Comment: The jupyterhub docs say `Note that by default privileged containers are not permitted in Gravity clusters. To allow privileged containers, enable them in your cluster manifest by setting systemOptions.allowPrivileged field to true.`, you might need to do that.

Comment: Could you provide also outputs of `kubectl describe psp <your-podsecuritypolicy-name>`, `kubectl get <psp-name>`, `whoami` (if user you are logged in is the same in psp). What exactly On-Prem? Azure, AWS, GKE?

Comment: I have `systemOptions.allowPrivileged ` set at true

Comment: I have moved off gravity for now. But if I get back, I'll def post here.